# ctrl+U doesn't work to clear my Terminal Screen

Tags: macos, terminal, command

Sorry for the silly question...

How do I clear my terminal screen? Cause ctrl+U just doesn't seem to work. Or do I need to assign this command somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Ctrl-U clears the current input line from the cursor back to the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. In alternative, you can run `clear` command.